# Can't change cursor color in emacsclient

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

If I run `emacs --daemon` (in `.xinitrc` or later) and then `emacsclient -c`, newly created frame has black cursor color, regardless on colortheme or any other settings. More exactly, before I type anything, the cursor color is white (or other color), but with first keypresses it becomes black and cannot be changed via `set-cursor-color`. Both default and my custom colorthemes are black, so it makes editing very uncomfortable.

If I run `emacs` and `M-x server-start` instead of `emacs --daemon` then this problem does not appear. But this way I need to keep one emacs "main" frame and not kill it incidentally, this doesn't seem like a nice solution.

I have following block in `.emacs.d/init.el` but it doesn't help:

```
(set-cursor-color "red")
(setq initial-frame-alist '((cursor-color . "red")))
(setq default-frame-alist '((cursor-color . "red")))
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook '(lambda () (set-cursor-color "red")))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions '(lambda (f) (with-selected-frame f (set-cursor-color "red"))))
```

If I run `M-x describe-face RET cursor` I get:

```
(...)
Defined in `faces.el'.

        Family: unspecified
       Foundry: unspecified
         Width: unspecified
        Height: unspecified
        Weight: unspecified
         Slant: unspecified
    Foreground: unspecified
    Background: black
     Underline: unspecified
      Overline: unspecified
Strike-through: unspecified
           Box: unspecified
       Inverse: unspecified
       Stipple: unspecified
          Font: unspecified
       Fontset: unspecified
       Inherit: unspecified
```

Comment: any news on the matter, did you find anything that worked in the end? I'm facing a similar issue where the color-theme won't be loaded by emacsclient, but emacs will happily apply my purple cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Alright.. This issue can be resolved by adding
>
> ```
> (setq default-frame-alist '((cursor-color . "white")))
> ```
>
> though I don't understand why it was not a problem before.

See [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=110336) forum thread.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that in recent Emacsen, using frame properties to set the cursor color is not the preferred method. So **instead** of using `set-cursor-color` or `initial-frame-alist` / `default-frame-alist`, try:

```
(set-face-background 'cursor "red")
```

Or, perhaps:

```
(set-face-attribute 'cursor nil :background "red"`)
```

Comment: Hmm, odd. I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I tried both too, but also without success. I'm also affected by this peculiar behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Bwahahaha!  I think no-one has posted a solution for the past 2 years because you are all EVIL emacs users!

Truth be told, I'm trying out evil-mode at the moment myself and I just solved this problem on my system.  Put this in your .emacs file and smoke it:

```
'(evil-default-cursor (quote (t "white")))
```

I just opened [a bug](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/342/evil-default-cursor-setting-should-default) against the Evil repository in bitbucket.

For myself, I found that after the 6 years or so it took to really become proficient at emacs, the multi-key chords were hard on my tendons.  Evil-mode may allow me to use emacs again, which is a good thing.  As [Benedict](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978588/benedict) says (in the context of Functional Programming), "[Some evil is often necessary to get work done.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212515/why-is-tight-coupling-between-functions-and-data-bad/212537#212537)"  It seems that may apply to Emacs as well.

P.S.
For anyone feels this answer is just [DH0](http://www.paulgraham.com/disagree.html) or otherwise immature and inappropriate, the mostly tongue-in-cheek [feud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war) between Emacs and VI users has raged for years.  Emacs has it's own [Church of Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChurchOfEmacs), VI has the video game, [World War VI](http://wordwarvi.sourceforge.net/).  So it is no surprise that the most successful port of VI keybindings to Emacs was named evil-mode (evil has the word VI in it).  I like both editors and laud the evil developers who finally made VI keybindings work inside emacs.

Comment: Thanks Glen, I'm EVIL user already (though I never use normal mode/state). I corrected your command (replaced `'` with `setq`). It seems to work well for me. And even if for some reason cursor goes black again, I can repeat the command.

Comment: Since this is the only solution that works for me I'm accepting your answer. Though it's a bit unfair for emacs user who are not EVIL fans.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
(setq evil-default-cursor t) ;; Now evil takes the default cursors 
(set-cursor-color "white") ;; Set it to white
(set-mouse-color "white") ;; Same
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the very same issue, for years now.

In my case I do:

```
M-x
set-cursor-color
"white"<ENTER>
```

That works for me but I have to do this everytime, which sux..

Back in my old workplace I had this solved but I don't have the init.el that I used to have in my old workplace and now I need to figure this out all over again, hopefully someone in here will figure this out before me.